# How do I make an HTML page interpret a TXT file as HTML code?

Tags: html, txt

All I've found is how to display the data of the TXT file, but I want to be able to use that TXT file to be interpreted and used as HTML code to be displayed instead.

Comment: I do not know what do you mean. Do you means that you want the file suffix to be TXT(like github)? The server's protocol header should do the trick. If you mean other thigns, could you provide more detail, or give us a example?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean JavaScript, your only option would be to do something like this:

```js
fetch('/file.txt').then(e=>e.text()).then(txt=>{
  let txtFunc = new Function(txt)
  txtFunc()
})
```

Note that `eval` or `new Function` is not safe and should not be used in most cases.

Comment: I should have specified that I want it to be interpreted as HTML code. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Change the file suffix to `.html` instead of `.txt`

Comment: I want to be able to use the TXT as code, not convert it to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I used a very slightly modified version of [derder56](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13434314/derder56)'s code for this example that takes HTML code from a text file and outputs it in the `result` div. Of course, you could do anything with the result from the text file, such as outputting it in the console.

```js
<body>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>

<script>
    fetch('file.txt').then(e => e.text()).then(txt => {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = txt;
    })
</script>
```

Keep in mind that due to a [CORS security advisory](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/security/advisories/mfsa2019-21/#CVE-2019-11730), you wouldn't be able to do this with local files due to CORS requests [requiring HTTP or HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp).